# Logic for filling a dropdown is needed twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two pages sharing the same Dropdown control which need the same logic for filling the Dropdown. The code looks like:

```
private void FillDropDown(Guid indentifier)
{
DateTime start = GetStartFromSession;
DateTime end = GetEndFromSession;

List<DataToDisplay> dataToDisplay = Businesslogic.GetData(identifier, start,end);

dataToDisplay.Add(new DataToDisplay(){ID : Guid.Empty, Value: GetLocalResourceString("PleaseSelectText");

//some more logic....

dropDown.DataSource = dataToDisplay;
dropDown.DataBind();

}
```

The code is exactly the same in two pages. I am not a fan of creating a helper class which needs the Businesslogic, the control to fill etc. But as code duplication is bad, i don't like the current solution also. I was thinking about creating a new generic control but its only a Dropdownbox, nothing more.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: then pass the dropdown to the fillcommand and use that variable to be the dropdown to populate.

Comment: What do you think where I can place that code?

Comment: Well, somewhere logical and sensible, but, as its not tied to a form, you can place it in another class.. which would need access to the other variables you use.. or, you pass those too

Comment: dropdown will present only in 2 pages of your website or all the pages in website ?

Comment: That's the problem, the Page provides all methods for Businesslogic and Config Access and so I had to pass many things to the new class. But at this point it would be my preffered solution because I don't like the code duplication.

Comment: The Dropdown is only present in 2 places. It's a legacy application so in my opinion it is very unlikely that there are more usages to come